# Highlight the active thumbnail in a slideshow

Tags: javascript

Here's the slideshow embed code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Slideshow</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
#large {width:448px; height:336px; background:#000 url(http://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-ugFamEhbqPo/Thc6hoArbwI/AAAAAAAAABA/PFeHcJhR4Xw/s800/image1.jpg) no-repeat center;}
#thumbs {padding-top:12px; overflow:auto; white-space:nowrap; width:448px;}
img {padding:1px; width:80px; height:60px;}
img:hover {background:#00F;}
</style>
</head> 
<body> 
<div id="large"></div>  
<div id="thumbs"> 
<img src="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-hUXeHq5OxEo/Thc7hFFv3gI/AAAAAAAAABQ/Yh7omR8iwzI/s800/thumb1.jpg" alt="" onclick="document.getElementById('large').style.backgroundImage='url(http://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-ugFamEhbqPo/Thc6hoArbwI/AAAAAAAAABA/PFeHcJhR4Xw/s800/image1.jpg)';">  
<img src="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-JU5a-eDnOSg/Thc7g5UkwLI/AAAAAAAAABI/9aCyCMixWb4/s800/thumb2.jpg" alt="" onclick="document.getElementById('large').style.backgroundImage='url(http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-u5BHGxpr0rg/Thc6hLbDRKI/AAAAAAAAAA8/IvQWzJBvqjg/s800/image2.jpg)';"> 
<img src="http://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-TdbbNGFbDNk/Thc7g0IBSsI/AAAAAAAAABM/pxpntZaTVoQ/s800/thumb3.jpg" alt="" onclick="document.getElementById('large').style.backgroundImage='url(http://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-4AMWSfi8q7A/Thc6haUv1QI/AAAAAAAAABE/oRdTWawPi_c/s800/image3.jpg)';">
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

I wonder how I can highlight the active thumbnail so its background remains blue until I click another one.
I also like to avoid the inline JavaScript. Any feedback to improve the coding is appreciated!

Best regards

Mike